# Feedly API is returning session expired instead of letting me access the API from local node environment

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch-api

Using feedlys API with a node wrapper suggested from feedly to access its API. I am not getting successful logins. I have scoured the docs and any resources available and cannot find any answers so I'm reaching out to the Stack Overflow community to see if anyone has had experience with this platform.

I tried clearing the cache. I've tried using the fetch API instead of using the node wrapper I am trying to implement.

I installed the node package 'feedly'.

Added this code to my server:

```
const Feedly = require('feedly')

const f = new Feedly({
  client_id: 'client_id here',
  client_secret: 'client_secret here',
  base: 'https://cloud.feedly.com/v3/collections/',
  port: 8080
})

async function feedlyStream() {
  const results = await f.reads()
  return console.log('results', results)
}

feedlyStream();
```

It does take me to a page to log in, presumably this is the auth so then I can retrieve data.

I'm not a backend user and primarily front end so performing the task this way is new to me.

When I run `nodemon ./server.js` from the console, it takes me to a login page, like that of feedlys website but then I get the error 'session expired'. There is no other errors, not in the console etc.

I can get retrieve information when working with insomnia to test the API endpoints, with the same exact info as above plus a bearer token.

Here is the fetch version i have tried with is very similar to that of the insomnia input.

```
const URL = 'https://cloud.feedly.com/v3/collections/'
const proxyurl = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/";

window.onload = () => {
  fetch(proxyurl + URL, {
    credentials: 'same-origin',
    Accept: 'application/json',
    headers:
    {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer TOKEN GOES HERE',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'include',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      "client_id": "client_id here", 
      "method": "GET",
      "client_secret": "client_secret here",
    }
  })
    .then(function (data) {
      console.log('data from api', data.body);
      const here = document.getElementById("here")
      const bodyText = () => {
        if (data.body == null) {
          return "Nope, it's null"
        }
        return data.body;
      }
      here.innerHTML = bodyText();
    })
}
```

This is what I receive from the console log above

> data from api ReadableStreamlocked: false__proto__: ReadableStream

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

quite simply i was missing part of the fetch. I needed to transform the response into JSON. Not use to fetch or apis still and this was an obvious but annoying one.

```
      "method": "GET",
      "client_secret": "client_secret here",
    }
  })
.then(res => res.json();) // this is what i needed to add in :)
 .then(function (data) {
      console.log('data from api', data.body);
```